# what is Configuration File Path and loaded Configuration File in PHP

Tags: php

what is Configuration File Path and loaded Configuration File in PHP.

When i see the phpinfo() information, it shows Configuration File (php.ini) Path  and Loaded Configuration File with 2 different values. Which php.ini file is loaded. What is the meaning of 2 different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path` is the folder.
`Loaded Configuration File` is the file loaded.

Additonal note:
Sometime the hoster sets up a default php.ini and allows the user to create an own php.ini file (in every folder) to override settings in the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach [php.ini directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) there are Master Value and Local Value

Local values represents settings that you have on your specific /local/  host.
They can be changed via `.htaccess` or `ini_set()`

Answer (score 0):

you select the "Loaded Configuration File" to see php.ini file.
(ex:/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)